# IPagedList implements IList interface but

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have `IPagedList` interface which implements `IList` like this

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageIndex { get; }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to use this `IPagedList` to represent data with pagination.
I'm trying to convert existing code which was using `IList` to `IPagedList`

```
public IList<MyViewModel> Data
{
  get
  {         
    List<MyViewModel> myVal = new List<MyViewModel>();
    foreach (MyModel m in data)
    {
       myVal.Add(new MyViewModel(m));
    }
    return myVal;
  }
}
```

So, I'm wondering why this cannot be converted to

```
public IPagedList<MyViewModel> Data
{
   get
    ....
```

cause `IPagedList` implements `IList` and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IPagedList<T>` implements `IList<T>` and `List<T>` also implements `IList<T>`, that's correct.

But that doesn't mean that a `List<T>` can be converted into an `IPagedList<T>`. That are still two different types. Think about it: A Porsche is a car, a Peugeot is a car, still they aren't interchangable.

You need to have a concrete implementation of the `IPagedList<T>` interface. If you have one, you can use this code:

```
public IList<MyViewModel> Data 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        var myVal = new PagedList<MyViewModel>(); 
        foreach (MyModel m in data) 
        { 
            myVal.Add(new MyViewModel(m)); 
        } 
        return myVal; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> So, I'm wondering why this cannot be converted to `public IPagedList Data { get`

You can't use `List<T>` anymore since it do not implement your interface. You have create your own class that implements `IPagedList<T>`.

The more important question is that you have a `Data` property that returns a paged list. It's not obvious how the paging should be handled.

The first though it that it lazy load each page when you enumerate the list. But that's not the case? You might want to rethink your design.

I would instead create a new interface using composition:

```
interface IPagedResult<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageIndex { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Page {get; }
}
```

It's more obvious that a single page is returned, and you do not have to create your own list class.

Comment: +1. "Composition over inheritance" seems to hold very well here :)

Comment: This interface is simple and exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that myVal return a list that was implemented from IList not your interface IPageList.